# React add and remove EventListener to handle search bar

Tags: reactjs, removeeventlistener

I don't get to understand why I can't get rid of my eventListener in this code.
The problem is that when I click the search icon to open and then close the searchbar, the 'keydown' eventListener doesn't terminate, it is still there and if I hit Escape key after that it will blur my actual component.
Can you help me with that please?

my code :

```
function handleSearchBar(e) {
       let actualComponent = document.querySelector("#actualComponent");
       let searchIcon = document.querySelector("#search_icon");
       if( e.keyCode === 27 || searchIcon.hasAttribute('enabled') ) {
            setSearchBar(() => false)
            searchIcon.toggleAttribute("enabled")
            actualComponent.classList.toggle("blur-sm")
          document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSearchBar);
            
      }else{

        setSearchBar(() => true)
        searchIcon.toggleAttribute("enabled")
        actualComponent.classList.toggle("blur-sm")
        document.addEventListener("keydown", handleSearchBar);
       }


    }
```

Comment: please visit https://etwincorp.com/resatest/ to exeperience the issue :)
If you click 2 times on the serach icon and then on escape you will see the problem I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
Bring `removeEventListener` outside of the `if else`:

```
function handleSearchBar(e) {
  let actualComponent = document.querySelector("#actualComponent");
  let searchIcon = document.querySelector("#search_icon");
  if (e.keyCode === 27 || searchIcon.hasAttribute('enabled')) {
    setSearchBar(() => false);
    searchIcon.toggleAttribute("enabled");
    actualComponent.classList.toggle("blur-sm");
  } else {
    setSearchBar(() => true);
    searchIcon.toggleAttribute("enabled");
    actualComponent.classList.toggle("blur-sm");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleSearchBar);
  }
  document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSearchBar);
}
```